# Fetching a csv file from a GWT app using requestbuilder - getting exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets, file-io

My goal is to try and read a csv file located on a server from within a servlet in my GWT app.

I tried this approach initially

```
public String[] convertFileToStringArrays(String pathToCSV) 
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try 
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToCSV));
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String currLine;
    String [] string_arrays = null;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null )
        {
            System.out.println(currLine);
            string_arrays[i] = currLine;
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return string_arrays;
}
```

However, I was getting a Java IO type exception. I found out that using the above method is not possible as the GWT apps donot have access to the Java IO libraries. 
So I googled around and found that people were saying the way to read a file in a GWT app on a server is to use Request Builder. So i tried the following approach using some samples I saw on the web. In this piece the file is located on my local filesystem and Im passing a path through the PathToCSV variable:

```
public String[] convertFileToStringArrays(final String pathToCSV)
{
     RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, pathToCSV);
     try
     {
         rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback()
         {
            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) 
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to load file:"+ pathToCSV);

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request,Response response) 
            {
                //TO DO currently just using this until the method is functional and can retrieve the file
                String resp = response.getText();

            }

         });
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());

     }

    return null;



}
```

}

However this code is throwing another exception:

Exception stacktrace:

```
Jun 26, 2012 7:29:41 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
```

SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String[] cs310.client.CsvFileParserService.convertFileToStringArrays(java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest.create()Lcom/google/gwt/xhr/client/XMLHttpRequest;
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest.create()Lcom/google/gwt/xhr/client/XMLHttpRequest;
    at com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest.create(Native Method)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder.doSend(RequestBuilder.java:369)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder.sendRequest(RequestBuilder.java:256)
    at cs310.server.CsvFileParserServiceImpl.convertFileToStringArrays(CsvFileParserServiceImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 34 more

I was wondering if anyone can help me to understand whether Im on the right track using this code to read a csv file into my app? If so then what can I do to resolve this exception. If not then are there any samples of code that do the same?

---

ADDED New code after trying URL connectin method

```
public String[] convertFileToStringArrays(final String pathToCSV)
{
    String [] string_arrays = null;
     try {
            URL url = new URL(pathToCSV);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String currLine;

            int i = 0;
            while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null )
                {
                    System.out.println(currLine);
                    string_arrays[i] = currLine;
                    i++;
                }
            br.close();

        } 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ...
        }
    if(string_arrays == null)
        System.out.println("CsvFilePasrserServiceImpl says that string_arrays is null");
        return string_arrays;

}
```

This results in this stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String[]     cs310.client.CsvFileParserService.convertFileToStringArrays(java.lang.String)' threw an     unexpected exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied     (java.io.FilePermission /Users/AM/Sites/new_food_vendor_locations2.csv read)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
at     com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at     com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at    com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at    com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /Users/AM/Sites/new_food_vendor_locations2.csv read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:252)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:752)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:65)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at cs310.server.CsvFileParserServiceImpl.convertFileToStringArrays(CsvFileParserServiceImpl.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
... 34 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you were having with `java.io` was not because of GWT, but because of [AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist). GWT is client-side, and that's why it now fails when you try to use `RequestBuilder` on the server-side.

To fetch URLs from the server-side on AppEngine, use the [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/).

Comment: Please see my edited section above in the post. I tried that code based on your suggestions. however, Im getting a fileaccess exception now.:(